# Facing issue on storybook run react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs, storybook

Got below issue when run 'npm run storybook'

FirstDemo@0.0.1 storybook

> start-storybook -p 7007
> throw err;
> ^
> Error: Cannot find module 'projectpath\node_modules\rxjs\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
> at tryPackage

Comment: what version of storybook are you using?

Comment: I used the latest version 5.3.25